# Using proof by contradiction to show that $x<y \implies \sqrt x < \sqrt y$

Tags: proof-verification

Let $x,y$ be positive real numbers. Use a proof by contradiction to prove that
$x < y \implies \sqrt x < \sqrt y$.
I assumed that x < y and I also assumed that to the contrary that $\sqrt x\ge \sqrt y$. Then if you square both sides you end up getting $x \ge y$ which is a contradiction, but I'm not sure if what I did is valid.

Comment: It is obviously correct

Comment: Actually, it is a proof by contrapositive: to rove $p\implies q$, you prove  $\neg q\implies\neg p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct.  If you want to use contradiction to prove that $P \implies Q$, you assume $P \land \lnot{Q}$ and look for a contradiction.

If you find a contradiction, then you now know that the negation of your assumption must be true; thus,

$\lnot{(P \land \lnot{Q})}$

Which, using DeMorgan's law, can be rewritten as follows:

$\lnot{P} \lor Q$

Which in turn is equivalent to the following:

$P \implies Q$

Thus, you have proven the implication that you set out prove.  In your problem, $P$ is the statement $x < y$, while $Q$ is the statement $\sqrt{x} < \sqrt{y}$, and you followed the above procedure exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct. If you want to be  a bit pedantic you can write that:

since $\sqrt x>0$ and $\sqrt y>0$ than:
$$
\sqrt x \ge \sqrt y \Rightarrow \sqrt x \sqrt x\ge \sqrt y \sqrt x \iff x\ge \sqrt y\sqrt x
$$
and

$$
\sqrt x \ge \sqrt y \Rightarrow \sqrt x \sqrt y\ge \sqrt y \sqrt y \iff  \sqrt x\sqrt y
\ge y$$

so (by transitivity) $x\ge y$ that contradicts $x<y$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x < y$, why does it follow that $x^2 < y^2$? If you know that, then your contradiction is fine.  But other wise consider why that is true.

It's because $x^2 = x*x < x*y < y*y = y^2$.  (And by induction this will hold for all positive integer powers.)  Now do your contradiction with confidence. Or do it directly. $x = \sqrt x * \sqrt x ?? \sqrt y * \sqrt y = y$.  So x and y and root x and root y must have the same relationship.